# Why is it not enough to change just nextNode in this data structure?

Tags: java, data-structures

In the following data structure

```
public class ListNode<T> {
    T data;
    ListNode<T> nextNode;

    ListNode(T object) {
        this(object, null);
    }

    ListNode(T object, ListNode<T> node) {
        data = object;
        nextNode = node;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public ListNode<T> getNextNode() {
        return nextNode;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class List<T> {
    private ListNode<T> firstNode;
    private ListNode<T> lastNode;
    private String name;

    public List() {
        this("list");
    }

    public List(String listName) {
        name = listName;
        firstNode = lastNode = null;
    }

    public void insertAtFront(T insertItem) {
        if(isEmpty()) firstNode = lastNode = new ListNode<T>(insertItem);
        else  firstNode = new ListNode<T>(insertItem, firstNode);
    }

    public void insertAtBack(T insertItem) {
        if(isEmpty()) firstNode = lastNode = new ListNode<T>(insertItem, null);
        else lastNode = lastNode.nextNode = new ListNode<T>(insertItem)
    }


}
```

why is it not sufficient to do just

```
        else lastNode.nextNode = new ListNode<T>(insertItem)
```

in the insertAtBack method? (I am also not sure what `a = b = c = something` mean in java.)

Comment: Because if you did that, `lastNode` wouldn't be the last node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not sufficient just to do this:

```
else lastNode.nextNode = new ListNode<T>(insertItem)
```

because the `List` needs to keep track of its first and last nodes.  When you insert at the back, you must update the `lastNode`, otherwise `lastNode` will refer to the "old" last node, now second-to-last.

If the list is initially empty, then neither the first nor the last node is set to anything; they must be initialized.

The `a = b = c = something` syntax assigns the last value/expression to all variables not last, associating right-to-left, e.g. `something` gets assigned to `c`, then `b`, and then `a`.

Comment: But shouldn't the lastNode.nextNode always point to null? I mean in this case lastNode.nextNode points back to lastNode. This looks a little strange to me.

Comment: That's why the order of multiple `=` is important.  When `lastNode.nextNode =` is executed, `lastNode` is still the "old" last node, so the old last node is pointed to the new node.  Then the `lastNode =` is executed, updating `lastNode` to the new node.

Comment: It might be clearer to rewrite it without the compound assignment.

Answer (score 0):

All credit to @rgettman, I will add an illustration for myself and readers:

[image]